# Slow reading from socket and inputStream

Tags: java, performance, sockets, stream, inputstream

I use java.net.Socket to receive message in my application. Receiving is very slow. Receiving 250 kB lasts over 7 seconds. What can I do to accelerate this. 7 seconds is too much...

```
InputStream is = null;
byte[] arr = new byte[8192];
try {
    is = client.getInputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int bytesNumber;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

try {
    while ((bytesNumber = is.read(arr)) >= 0) {
        if (bytesNumber == 8192) {
            sb.append(arr);
            continue;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesNumber; i++) {
                sb.append(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what is `tab`?  You have `is.read(tab)`

Comment: First off, your code is completely incorrect with the way you're appending stuff. Second, code is usually not the limitation in the speed at which data is received - the client's upload speed and server's download speed are generally the reason speed is limited.

Comment: So what is the best way to quick read the data?

Answer (score 0):

it is beacouse you are appending one character by one if you read less than your buffer (arr) length. Append the whole buffer content instead, no need for the if:

```
sb.append(arr,0,butesNumber);
```

Comment: well convert it to the string then. Nevertheless the problem is the apending one by one content of your arr.

Comment: I really doubt that this loop will have any impact on execution time, even it is not the correct way.

Comment: There is only one way to be sure :) Probably server part is also sending bytes one by one ...

Answer (score 0):

As tinker mentioned, usually the big limitation is the client and server network.  But you can greatly simplify what you have.  Also, your buffer size of 8K is way too small, in my opinion.  Use 1M or larger unless you have serious memory constraints.

```
public String readClient(Client client) throws IOException{
    final int bufferSize = 1024 << 9;

    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream(),bufferSize);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
    int bytesRead;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);
    try {
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            sb.append(new String(bytes, 0, bytesRead));
        }
    }finally {
        in.close();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: why do you preallocate buffferSize/2 for a string buffer?

Comment: Because being consistent is just so boring.

Comment: Why would he need a 1M buffer for 250k files? The application buffers should match the send/receive buffers for the underlying socket.

Comment: Whose to say it will always be 250K?  I don't believe there needs to be a limit.  The JDK reads into the stream buffer until blocked by the socket.  The socket may not block with a smaller buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Performance this bad is unlikely to be due to your code. What kind of performance do you get using `curl` or something like that between the same systems?

The bigger problem is that your code is unlikely to do what you want. Currently, you are appending the representation of a byte array to a string, or appending the decimal representation of a byte to that string. If the server sends "Hello, World!", you'll end up with a string that says "7210110810811144328711111410810033". For longer files, you'll see something like "[B@76c5a2f7" popping up, which is how byte arrays are printed.

I'd write it something like this, assuming that you are receiving text encoded with UTF-8:

```
CharArrayWriter str = new CharArrayWriter();
try (InputStream is = client.getInputStream()) {
  Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  char[] buffer = new char[8192];
  while (true) {
    int n = r.read(buffer);
    if (n < 0)
      break;
    str.write(buffer, 0, n);
  }
}
System.out.println(str);
```